# How to download opensso-springsecurity-0.3 jar (maven dependency and repo url)

Tags: opensso

1)opensso-springsecurity jar is needed to integrate opensso with 
spring security-3 web project
but either repository url has changed or jar is not available.

I tried to checkout code base from svn repository and build it. But built jar is not working